# stopPropagation not work in absolute positioned elements

Tags: jquery

i have a container, it has no.of child element. i just what to add a click event to my container (#container). for that i use this function,

```
$(document).delegate("#container", 'click', function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
alert(this.tagName); // it show the "div", but i clicked on "a"
})
```

it works fine. but i have absolutly positioned no of images, and 'a' elements, but in case if i click on the image or a, it works like container div... how can i avoid this? any help?

Comment: Can you show a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces the problem, please?

Comment: this is happening with my ipad apps.. i think it is very strange to put to jsFidle, is it there any way to fix this?

Comment: You're binding an event to the document, which means the event has already bubbled by the time the event fires, which means, of course, that it *can't*, in any way, stop propagation (because it's *already* propagated). Try binding to an element that's closer to the `#container` element, and stop propagation at *that* point.

Answer (score 0):

`this` always will be `#container`, because that's the element the event is "bound" to.

Try using `e.target` instead of `this`.  `e.target` will always be the element the event was triggered on, and `this` will be the element it's "bound" to.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/usmjr/2/

P.S. `stopPropagation` doesn't work with `.delegate`, because `delegate` works by propagating the event, so you can't stop propagation.  You can have other events stop propagation to the delegated event, but not once you've hit the delegated event.  http://api.jquery.com/delegate/#notes-0